# Why does the variable _count always return -1?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Environment: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6
Server version: 5.6.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
phpMyAdmin:  4.0.9

The following procedure returns a -1 always even when the _count > 0, and the updates to the data are completed.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `forgotten_password_update`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `forgotten_password_update`(
IN _password longtext,
IN _salt varchar(255),
IN _parameter varchar(255),
IN _id bigint(20)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count tinyint(1);
    SELECT COUNT(*) into _count FROM forgot_password_reset WHERE parameter = _parameter AND user_id = _id AND is_reset = FALSE AND NOW() <= datetime_expiry;
    IF _count > 0 THEN
        UPDATE forgot_password_reset SET is_reset = TRUE, datetime_reset = NOW() WHERE _parameter = _parameter AND id = _id AND is_reset = FALSE;
        UPDATE login SET password = _password, salt = _salt WHERE id = _id;
    ELSE
        SET _count = -1;
    END IF;
    SELECT _count as num_of_updated_records;
END//


DELIMITER END;
```

I have run this using the MySQL console in phpMyAdmin. If the _count >0 the updates have completed successfully and the _count returns -1.

If the _count < 0, the updates do not run, and the _count returns a -1.

I am confused as to why the _count is being set as -1?

```
CALL `forgotten_password_update`('PASSWORD_ONE','SALT1', 'test2', 2);
CALL `forgotten_password_update`('Test1234','SALT2', 'test2', 2);
```

Here are set-up scripts to create the tables above for forgot_password_reset and login:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `login`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
  `login_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` longtext,
  `salt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`),
)


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `forgot_password_reset`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forgot_password_reset` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `parameter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `is_reset` boolean default false,
    `datetime_reset` datetime default NULL,
    `datetime_expiry` datetime default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES login(`id`)
)
```

EDIT: Data to insert:

```
INSERT INTO `login` (login_id, password, salt) VALUES (2, 'temp_password', '0000');
INSERT INTO `forgot_password_reset` (user_id, parameter, datetime_expiry) VALUES (2, 'test2', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I can't reproduce the problem. Also, please note that your code snippet calls procedure `forgotten_password_url_update` while you provided the definition for a procedure named `forgotten_password_update`. Are you testing the correct procedure?

Comment: Will update it shortly, with code inserts. Forgot to remove the other _url!

Comment: Completed. Please refer to the last part for the data inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this using the mysql command line and the issue is with the phpMyAdmin console. I am closing this since the answer comes back correctly in the command line window.